# How do I convert a PowerShell script with custom modules into a single executable?

Tags: powershell, module, compilation, exe

I've written a simple script that has multiple custom functions stored as modules. I have done it this way because I was always been told that if your function can be reused by other things then it should be a module and not a .\ source include. I'm starting to think that mantra isn't right in my current scenario. I am trying to convert the script to an single .exe so that I can install it as a windows service.

Probably should acknowledge that I understand why you wouldn't want to include system modules like Active Directory or IIS management for the obvious issue that could lead to but I'm only trying to include custom functions in a single disputable non editable way.

I have used PowerGUI in the past but can't find any valid exe's for that since DELL have removed it and from memory, I don't think I've ever used it with a module.

I've tried PS2EXE-GUI and PS2EXE. Both of these make the exe and everything works fine while the modules exist. However, as soon as I put the exe on a server that hasn't got the Modules deployed to it, it fails to run. I thought the compile followed all the dependencies and included them as part of the build into the single exe? That appears to not be the case.

I've also tried the PowerShell Studio 2018 by Sapien, but based on their forums you can't include modules into the complied exe. Which again feels wrong if they are actually just custom functions, but it's the way they've written it.

I see https://poshtools.com/docs/posh-pro-tools/merge-script/ would possibly do what I need but that's chargeable and it looks like it actually merges all the content back into a single file. Given the time pressure I'm starting to think I'll have to pay if there are really no other better options. I just don't have time to join everything together manually and I can't help thinking there is a better way I'm missing!

Can anybody please suggest other options?

Could I also get clarification around my original mantra (functions go in modules...)?

"No, never!" or "Yes, always!" or "It's just wrong in this scenario."

Comment: If the functions are interrelated or directly dependent on each other you should probably put them all in _the same module_

Comment: Thanks, typically its functions like Send-Email, Get-html, Check-NetworkInfo and Write-CustomError. Each Module has its own config file for configuring settings unique to that module like SMTP Server address, SMTP Username. if I get a bunch of functions that share commonality I'll put them together. So one module might be communications focused and contain both the Write-CustomError & Send-Email functions. 
Each module / function can be standalone from any other.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I use ps2exe to ship my scripts to users as an EXE file. Now that my scripts grew bigger I want to start to reuse some code and put it in modules, but as I found out it ps2exe does not include modules when compiling EXE file, so now just sharing EXE file with users is not an option. Would appreciate any help on this.